# Find key or value in Dictionary<double, double> with linear interpolation

Tags: c#, search, dictionary, interpolation

I am developing application with .NET 4.5 / C# 6.0 which gets measurement data from a hardware device, which is also configured by my application. E.g. I configure my device with the following:

- start frequency: 10 kHz
- stop frequency:  20 kHz
- measurement points: 11

and at the end of the processing pipeline of my raw data I get a dictionary like the following, where the key is the frequency and the value e.g. the magnitude in dB:

> key => value
>   10k => -3
>   11k => -3
>   12k => -3
>   13k => -3.5
>   14k => -4
>   15k => -5
>   16k => -6
>   17k => -7
>   18k => -8
>   19k => -10
>   20k => -12

This dictionary is updated "on the fly" as the device is continuously sweeping these 11 points in a loop.
These values are for once displayed in a chart, which is no problem as I simply update the chart data whenever a new point is ready (I get an event for each new point), but I also have a data grid where the user can display the values for manually entered points ([value] means manually entered), e.g.:

```
        | A: f       | B: mag(db)  
Point 1 | [11 kHz]   | -3 dB
Point 2 | [16.5 kHz] | -6.5 dB
Point 3 | 18.5 kHz   | [-9.5 dB]
```

`Point 1` is easy as it hits exactly on one measured point, but for e.g. `Point 2` the user manually enters `16.5 kHz` in column A, which means I need to interpolate the value of column B for the two measurement points next to it.
About the same, but the other way around for `Point 3`: The user manually entered `-9.5 dB` in column B and so I need to find the interpolated frequency where this value would be the interpolated result.

Note - the following constraints apply for `Point 3`:

- If the value would be possible twice or more, the first one is used, e.g. for `-3 dB` it should return `10 kHz`
- The frequency for the entered value is only searched once and then it behaves the same as `Point 2`
- If the given value is not found the closest one is returned (also valid for `Point 2`), e.g. values > `-3 dB` return `10 kHz` and values < `-12 dB` return `20 kHz`

**Is there some fast/optimized way to get to these values for `Point 2` and `Point 3`?**

I could only think of iterating over all point every time a value is manually entered and then interpolate between every two points until the given value is found. Then update column B when one of the neighboring frequencies is updated.
Note: The device delivers up to several hundred points per second.